# How Do I Use A Tuple Properly in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, tuples, models

I'm trying to use two models in one view using a tuple but I'm getting this error:
Server Error in '/' Application.

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[S00117372CA3.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Tuple`2[PagedList.IPagedList`1[S00117372CA3.Product],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[S00117372CA3.Order]]'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'PagedList.PagedList`1[S00117372CA3.Product]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Tuple`2[PagedList.IPagedList`1[S00117372CA3.Product],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[S00117372CA3.Order]]'.

Here is my code:

```
    @*@model PagedList.IPagedList<S00117372CA3.Product>*@
@model Tuple<PagedList.IPagedList<S00117372CA3.Product>, IEnumerable<S00117372CA3.Order>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].ProductName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].Supplier.CompanyName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].Category.CategoryName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].QuantityPerUnit)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].UnitPrice)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].UnitsInStock)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].UnitsOnOrder)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].ReorderLevel)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item1[0].Discontinued)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Item1) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Supplier.CompanyName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityPerUnit)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsInStock)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsOnOrder)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReorderLevel)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discontinued)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<div>
    Page @(Model.Item1.PageCount < Model.Item1.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.Item1.PageNumber) of @Model.Item1.PageCount
    @if (Model.Item1.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1})
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new {page = Model.Item1.PageNumber - 1})
    }
    else{
     @:<<
     @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev   
    }

    @if (Model.Item1.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new {page = Model.Item1.PageNumber + 1})
        @Html.Raw(" "); 
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new {page = Model.Item1.PageCount})
    }
    else{
     @:Next >
     @Html.Raw(" ")
@:>>   
    }
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model.Item2)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Orders")
}
```

Here is my controller code as requested:

```
var q = (from o in db.Order_Details
                     where o.ProductID == id
                     join ord in db.Orders
                     on o.OrderID equals ord.OrderID
                     orderby o.Quantity descending
                     select ord);
            var qm = q.Take(3);
            return PartialView("_Orders", qm.ToList());
```

Comment: Why use a `Tuple`? Wrap both objects in an enclosing class. It's much nicer.. and will work with the model binder too.

Comment: because I don't know how to do that. If you could post an example and a link that would be fantastic. Thanks

Comment: The problem is, in your controller, you are passing the wrong data type to the View.  Whats your controller code?

Comment: Hi Keith, Posted the controller code for the relevant action result

Comment: Also, I should say that the partial view is only ment to be called once the details link is clicked. Have I dont this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially, you're just trying to pass multiple models to your view.  As you can only pass one type to a view, the way to do what you want is to wrap your models in a view model and pass that to your view instead.  Something like:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ProductViewModel();
    model.Products = // ... fetch from database
    model.Orders = // ... fetch from database

    return View(model);
}
```

The view can now be strongly-typed to the view model:

```
@model ProductViewModel
```

Comment: IPagedList is any new class supplied with .net ?

Comment: @Thomas You can find it on [github](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/IPagedList.cs).