# View returns null value when using two models in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a simple MVC program where earlier I was using one model and the code was working fine. here is the code.

**View**

```
@model Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Create User</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Create User</h2><br />

 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create",
                           "CreateUsers",
                           new { id = Model != null ? Model.ObjectId : "" },
                           FormMethod.Post,
                           new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
                   )
 {

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserPrincipalName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPrincipalName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserPrincipalName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountEnabled)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AccountEnabled)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AccountEnabled)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PasswordProfile.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PasswordProfile.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordProfile.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MailNickname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MailNickname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MailNickname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DisplayName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GivenName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GivenName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GivenName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Department)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Department)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Department)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
</body>
</html>
 @if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage == "AuthorizationRequired")
 {
    <p>You have to sign-in. Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "Create", "Users", new { reauth = true }, null) to sign-in.</p>
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string blobDetails)
    {
        #region POPULATE USER DETAIL IN CREATEUSER FIELDS

        List<string> userDetails = blobDetails.Split(',').ToList();

        User user = new User();
        user.UserPrincipalName = userDetails[2] + "@xxx.com";
        user.GivenName = userDetails[0];
        user.Surname = userDetails[1];
        user.DisplayName = userDetails[0] + " " + userDetails[1];

        return View(Tuple.Create(user);

        #endregion
    }

     [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include ="UserPrincipalName,AccountEnabled,PasswordProfile,MailNickname,DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,JobTitle,Department")] User user)
    {
        ActiveDirectoryClient client = null;
        client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

        string name = user.GivenName;
        string username = user.UserPrincipalName;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And this works perfectly fine , I get the values of user.GivenName and user.UserPrincipalName from view and I store it into string. Now what I am doing is that I am including one more model into this and trying to get its value from view so I did something like this:

**Model**

```
public class CreateUsers
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PIDetails { get; set; }
    public string BlobDetails { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using WebAppGraphAPI.Models
@model Tuple<Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User, CreateUsers>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Create User</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Create User</h2><br />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create",
                        "CreateUsers",
                        new { id = Model != null ? Model.Item1.ObjectId : "" 
 },
                        FormMethod.Post,
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
                )
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>User</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.UserPrincipalName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.UserPrincipalName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.UserPrincipalName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.AccountEnabled)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.AccountEnabled)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.AccountEnabled)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.PasswordProfile.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.PasswordProfile.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.PasswordProfile.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.MailNickname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.MailNickname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.MailNickname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.DisplayName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.DisplayName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.DisplayName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.GivenName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.GivenName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.GivenName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Surname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Surname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Surname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.JobTitle)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.JobTitle)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.JobTitle)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Department)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Department)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(tuple => tuple.Item1.Department)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @*@Html.LabelFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.UserEmail)*@
    @Html.EditorFor(tuple => tuple.Item2.UserEmail)
</div>
</body>
</html>
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage == "AuthorizationRequired")
{
<p>You have to sign-in. Click @Html.ActionLink("here", "Create", "Users", new { reauth = true }, null) to sign-in.</p>
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string blobDetails)
    {
        #region POPULATE USER DETAIL IN CREATEUSER FIELDS

        List<string> userDetails = blobDetails.Split(',').ToList();

        User user = new User();
        user.UserPrincipalName = userDetails[2] + "@gwuadmeaoutlook.onmicrosoft.com";
        user.GivenName = userDetails[0];
        user.Surname = userDetails[1];
        user.DisplayName = userDetails[0] + " " + userDetails[1];

        CreateUsers userInfo = new CreateUsers();
        userInfo.UserEmail = userDetails[4];
        return View(Tuple.Create(user,userInfo));
    }

   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include ="UserPrincipalName,AccountEnabled,PasswordProfile,MailNickname,DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,JobTitle,Department")] User user,[Bind(Include ="UserEmail")] CreateUsers userInfo)
    {
        ActiveDirectoryClient client = null;
        client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

        string name = user.GivenName;
        string username = user.UserPrincipalName;
        string Email = userInfo.UserEmail

        return RedirectToAction("Index");

   }
```

When I do this I do not get values from View in my controller strings , it shows null. Can you suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using a Tuple instead of creating a model for your data transformation? Also, have you looked into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118310/ado-net-mvc3-tuple-using-in-model-and-single-views or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105216/how-do-i-use-a-tuple-properly-in-asp-net-mvc-4?

Comment: I have created model for CreateUsers , other one is a microsoft client library .Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User

Comment: I'd recommend you have a model which has all of your data in it. MVC really expects this instead of multiple objects. While the Tuple could work, it seems to have issues based on the referenced links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an object which contains all of the properties you're trying to send to the client. We generally create DTOs for this specific usage. In you're case you'd have:

**CreateDto**

```
public class CreateDto
{
    public Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User User { get; set; }
    public CreateUsers UserInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then you're controller will be updated as:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(string blobDetails)
{
    #region POPULATE USER DETAIL IN CREATEUSER FIELDS

    List<string> userDetails = blobDetails.Split(',').ToList();

    User user = new User();
    user.UserPrincipalName = userDetails[2] + "@gwuadmeaoutlook.onmicrosoft.com";
    user.GivenName = userDetails[0];
    user.Surname = userDetails[1];
    user.DisplayName = userDetails[0] + " " + userDetails[1];

    CreateUsers userInfo = new CreateUsers();
    userInfo.UserEmail = userDetails[4];

    var dto = new CreateDto() {
        User = user,
        UserInfo = userInfo
    }
    return View(dto);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include ="UserPrincipalName,AccountEnabled,PasswordProfile,MailNickname,DisplayName,GivenName,Surname,JobTitle,Department")] User user,[Bind(Include ="UserEmail")] CreateUsers userInfo)
{
    ActiveDirectoryClient client = null;
    client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();

    string name = user.GivenName;
    string username = user.UserPrincipalName;
    string Email = userInfo.UserEmail

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

And your view will have:

```
@using WebAppGraphAPI.Models
@model CreateDto
```

Later you can reference the information with Model.user and Model.userInfo.

I know this doesn't explain why the Tuple doesn't work. I believe that is best explain by @darin-dimitrov in [ado.net mvc3 tuple using in model and single views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118310/ado-net-mvc3-tuple-using-in-model-and-single-views)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I applied your method and It works now. However I still dont know what is the issue. I am marking you answer as accepted.

Comment: I agree. The best I could tell was the answer stating that a Tuple doesn't have a default constructor, and for some reason that's required for models passed to a view. That answer doesn't make sense, but it's the only explanation I can think of.